# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'

Tags: python, django

working with legacy **django 1.3.1** , having problem in using the url name patterns in the template.

**urls.py** :

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'project.views',

    url(r'^web/login/', 'login', name="web_login"),

)
```

in **views** rendering template like:

```
return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in **template** using the url naming pattern like

```
<form id="loginForm" action="{% url web_login %}" method="POST">
```

Getting the error while rendering the template

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'

Comment: How about including full traceback?

Comment: did you include this line? `from django.conf.urls import patterns, url` into your urls.py ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some quote marks.

```
action="{% url 'web_login' %}"
```

Comment: django1.3 you do not need that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: then complete with the `$` symbol: `url(r'^web/login/$',.....)` just for the sake of correctness :P

Comment: I thought it did. Then I saw he is using 1.3.1